# Windows cmd sort files by file type and store them in folder

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd, file-type

I would like to have a batch file wich will sort files by file type and sorts them into folder.
For example I will run this batch file in some folder and .PDF files will be saved in "PDF" folder, same to do with other file types. Is possible to do that in command line?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please put the code below in a .bat file and save it to your folder with files and run it.

```
@echo off
rem For each file in your folder
for %%a in (".\*") do (
    rem check if the file has an extension and if it is not our script
    if "%%~xa" NEQ ""  if "%%~dpnxa" NEQ "%~dpnx0" (
        rem check if extension forlder exists, if not it is created
        if not exist "%%~xa" mkdir "%%~xa"
        rem Copy (or change to move) the file to directory
        copy "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\"
    )
)
```

Comment: That's great, but it would be good to delete previous files in main directory after sorting.

Comment: Replace "copy" with "move" as instructions in comment "or change to move".

Comment: This won't move/copy .bat file and use huge memory resources. I've tested it on Win10 with hundreds of thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "fol=%%~xa" & set "fol=!fol:.=!"
   if not exist !fol! md !fol!
      for /f %%b in ('dir /on /b *.*') do (
         if %%~xb EQU .!fol! move %%~nxb !fol!
      )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET destdir=c:\destdir
SET "extdone=:"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d') DO (
 SET ext=%%~xa
 IF DEFINED ext (
  SET extdone|FIND /i ":%%~xa:" >NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   SET extdone=:%%~xa: !extdone!
   IF EXIST "%destdir%\!ext:~1!" (
    ECHO MOVE "*%%~xa" "%destdir%\!ext:~1!"
   ) ELSE (ECHO no MOVE "%%~xa")
  )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This batch should do as you ask.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.

I've assumed that you only wish to move the files if `destinationdirectory\extensionfound` exists. If you want to create a directory for a new extension, simply add a line

```
md "%destdir%\!ext:~1!" 2>nul
```

after the `SET extdone=:%%~xa: !extdone!` line.